# How do you run a function to compare two date by month?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a function to compare today's month with the month input by a user. The dates will be input by the user as 'YYYY-MM-DD'. This is what I have so far:

```
class Sneaker(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
date = models.DateField('release date')
price = models.IntegerField()

def worn_for_the_month(self):
    return self.worn_set.filter(date=date.today().month).count == date.month
```

But get the following error:

> fromisoformat: argument must be str

So I tried using the following function instead with string:

```
def worn_for_the_month(self):
    return self.worn_set.filter(date=str(date.month)) == str(date.month)
```

And I get this error:

> %(value)s” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

I'm not sure if I'm using the right type of function at this point. I just want to compare the month we're in with the one the user entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to just filter by only the month value then you can do something like this (`__month`):

```
def worn_for_the_month(self):
    return self.worn_set.filter(date__month=date.today().month).count()
```

However, I imagine you don't really want to do this because you will count those that were worn in July 2022 as well as July 2021, 2020, and so on... Instead you can use either `replace()` or `timedelta` from the datetime library:

```py
from datetime import datetime

""" replace the days to get the first of the month: """
today = datetime.now()
first_of_the_month = today.replace(day=1)
# output: datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 19, 54, 45, 95533)

""" use timedelta to get 31 days ago: """
one_month_ago = today - timedelta(days=31)
# output: datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 18, 19, 56, 15, 39065)
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have to indent all the items that are after the class sneaker to put those items inside the class. And then you forgot to import models. 'from django.db import models' would work.

Comment: Hi there, OP has provided just a snippet of the code which will exclude imports and might lack indentation due to formatting from the IDE into the stackoverflow editor - see my answer below for the fix

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).